# Uploading files within a foreach loop

Tags: php, file-upload

How can I access and upload an image file within a foreach loop, given that I'm currently unable to access the file even though the array from the POST request is working?

```
function Products($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $product_id = $row['product_id'];

        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $expensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPEG", "JPG", "PNG");

        $fileName = date('Ymdhis').".".$file_ext;

        // Insert Sample Function
        InsertFunction($fileName, $product_id);
    }
}

$array = array(
    array('product_id' => 1, 'file' => /*$_FILES 1*/),
    array('product_id' => 2, 'file' => /*$_FILES 2*/),
);

echo json_encode(Products($array));
```

I tried to pass the file variable on the `$_FILES` but it was not working.

Comment: Please post the code (minimal reproducible example) that you use for building `$data`

Comment: Use `var_dump($_FILES);` to inspect the structure of the FILES array. Then you'll be able to see how you'd need to loop through it. It's unclear what you've tried, or what "can't access" or "not working" mean in practice...they are vague and meaningless descriptions which give no details of what actually happened. Show your attempt and explain the exact error/problem you encountered, then we can help you to understand the mistake and correct it. We can't see what's actually in your FILES array either, unless you show us. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of the issue. Thanks.